# Sencha touch 2 + PhoneGap + Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, sencha-touch-2, multiplatform

I would like to know how to use Sencha touch 2 + PhoneGap + Sqlite because I made a lot of search and I didn't found something useful.
Someone can help me with a tutorial.
My app should store a lot of data locally in the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should start looking for phone gap plugins for sqlite functionality.

Take a look at https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin